# Signin with Apple throws invalid_client error

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, apple-login

I am trying to integrate apple login in my laravel app with larvel/socialite. I have created the app from developer account and using all the correct credentials. And generated the secret key using private key.
But I am facing the issue `Client error:` POST [https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token`](https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token%60) resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"invalid_client"}`.
I have followed [this tutorial](https://bannister.me/blog/generating-a-client-secret-for-sign-in-with-apple-on-each-request) to generate the client_secret_key using private auth key.

I read so many guides, forums discussion and tutorials and nothing works.